# Add elements within array with same field name in jq

Tags: json, jq

Need to add array elements with same field name

**Input**:

```
[
  {
    "all": 1,
    "sys": "bus"
  },
  {
    "all": 14,
    "sys": "bus"
  }
]
```

I have tried like below:

```
.[] | (.all +.all)
```

but got result like

```
2
28
```

Expected result: `15` (1 + 14)

Answer (score 1):

First map, then add:

```
map(.all) | add
```

C'est tout.